# Alternate way to retrieve data from core data database - ios

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am having performance issues while retrieving data from the database.

Right now, this is how I do it.

```
+(NSMutableArray *) searchObjectsInContext: (NSString*) entityName : (NSPredicate *) predicate : (NSString*) sortKey : (BOOL) sortAscending 

{
     i3EAppDelegate *appDelegate = (i3EAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
     [request setEntity:entity];     
     [request setFetchBatchSize:5];
    //[request setFetchLimit:10];
     [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

     // If a predicate was passed, pass it to the query
     if(predicate != nil)
     {
          [request setPredicate:predicate];
     }

     // If a sort key was passed, use it for sorting.
     if(sortKey != nil)
     {
          NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:sortAscending];
          NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
          [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
               [sortDescriptors release];
          [sortDescriptor release];
     }

     NSError *error;
     NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

     if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {

          // Handle the error.

          // NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

          exit(-1);  // Fail
          }

     [request release];
     //[context release];
     appDelegate = nil;

     return [mutableFetchResults autorelease];

}
```

Is there any other way to perform the same operation but in a faster way?

If so, it would be great if someone could help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You do not have a predicate. Therefore you are retrieving the entire table. That is probably your single biggest issue.
2. You are loading all of the full objects on retrieval. This is going to slow things down considerably. If you do not need the entire objects realized then I would suggest turning `-setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:` back on.
3. The setting of `-setFetchBatchSize:` is probably not having the effect you are expecting. If you want to limit the number of results returned use `-setFetchLimit:`
4. Making a `-mutableCopy` of the `NSArray` results has no value. I suspect you got that from a book and recommend you stop doing it.

Comment: Thank you marcus for the reply. I am setting a predicate.. I send the predicate when I call the function. I will look into "setReturnsObjectAsFaults" to see how I can use it. Also, thanks for pointing out about the -mutableCopy.. I would like to know how it affects my performance..

Comment: @learner2010, the -mutableCopy will not impact performance much but it is just wrong because it doesn't do anything useful. Unfortunately there was a bad example written that got spread around and I suspect that is where you got it from (I see it a **lot**).  Setting the fetch limit and returning as faults (empty objects) will be your biggest performance gains outside of a properly formatted `NSPredicate`. What does your `NSPredicate` look like?

Comment: here is what my predicate looks like.. `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"users == %@ && (startDate <= %@ && endDate >= %@)", objUser, todayDate, pastDate];`

Comment: Predicate looks ok although I would switch the `users` comparison to the end so that it is doing a numeric comparison first.  How much data are you dealing with here?

Comment: How many records in Core Data?  500-600 records is nothing to Core Data and should be nearly instantaneous.  Is there binary data in these records?  How big are they?

Comment: I am not exactly sure of how much data I store, but I receive around 300000 bytes of data from the webservice and I need to store all the data from it to the database.

Comment: Again that is a **VERY** small amount of data.  What is your performance like now?  Where does instruments show your hot spots to be?

Comment: It takes me around 15 seconds to fetch the data from the database. I was not aware that I could use my instruments for checking my hot spots. I will check it out first...

Comment: 15 seconds is definitely something wrong.  I would run the Time Profiler template against your app and find out where that time is being spent.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself a couple of questions about your data requirements.

Do you need access to all the results at once? If you only need a small number at a time you could retrieve only the `NSManagedObjectID`'s:

```
[request setResultType:NSManagedObjectIDResultType];
```

This will be very quick and give you a sorted list, but you'll have to retrieve the actual data as required.

If you need the data a bit faster you could retrieve faulted `NSManagedObject`'s

```
[request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
```

This will allocate the objects in advance, but won't fetch the actual data until you request it.

Alternatively do you need to perform the sort as part of the fetch, or if could you somehow do it quicker once the objects are in memory?

It is worth creating yourself a test harness and trying the various options to see which are most suitable for your application.