# Core-Data executeFetchRequest freezes App in a background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I have a `saveMOC` which is the direct parent of a `mainMOC`, and I need for online fetch another `tmpMOC` in order not to block my UI whilst fetching a ton of records from the Internet.

My app freezes.
I could narrow it to this very point:

```
       fetchedItems = [tmpMOC executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

I tried to enclose this within `dispatch_sync`, `[moc.parentcontext.parentcontext.persistentStoreCoordinator lock/unlock]`, `[whatevermoc performBlockAndWait]`...

I also try to fetch the `_mainMOC`... No way...

I understand that `executeFetchRequest`is not thread safe, so, how do I lock whatever I need to lock to get sure I am not inserting a double?

Anybody could help?

**UPDATE (1)**
`_saveMOC` instantiation in AppDelegate:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
if (_mainMOC != nil) {
    return _mainMOC;
}

if (_saveMOC == nil) {
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _saveMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_saveMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [_saveMOC setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
    }
}
if (_mainMOC == nil) {
    _mainMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_mainMOC setParentContext:_saveMOC];
    [_mainMOC setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy];
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveContextChanges:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:_mainMOC];
```

`temporaryMOC`creation in MainViewController:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
temporaryContext.parentContext = _mainMOC;

[temporaryContext performBlock:^{ //AndWait
    NSError *error=nil;
    Feed *feed=(Feed *)[temporaryContext existingObjectWithID:feedID error:&error];

//...
       [RSSParser parseRSSFeedForRequest:req success:^(NSArray *feedItems)
     {
         NSLog(@"[MasterViewController::fetchPosts] inserting %d Posts.../OK", (int)[feedItems count]);
         feed.valid = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
         for(RSSItem *i in feedItems)
         {
             [self createPostInFeed:feed withTitle:i.title withContent:(i.content?i.content:i.itemDescription) withURL:[i.link absoluteString] withDate:(i.pubDate?i.pubDate:[NSDate date]) inMOC:temporaryContext];
         }
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NewPostsFetched" object:f];
```

Then the freeze happens in `createPostInFeed`:

```
 // @synchronized(fetchRequest) { // THIS DOESN'T CHANGE ANYTHING
 // [moc.persistentStoreCoordinator lock]; // THIS NEITHER
 NSArray *fetchedItems;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    fetchRequest.entity = ent;

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"title", @"url", @"feed.name", nil];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@ AND url == %@ AND feed.rss == %@", title, url, feed.rss];
    NSError *error = nil;
    fetchedItems = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; // FREEZES HERE
// [moc.persistentStoreCoordinator unlock]; // THIS DOESN'T CHANGE ANYTHING
// } // Synchronized neither...
```

**Update (2):**
Here's what the Time Profiler sees.
[image]

**Update (3):**
Block edited:

```
NSUInteger fetchedItems;
NSString *feedRSS=feed.rss;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
fetchRequest.entity = ent;

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@ AND url == %@ AND feed.rss == %@", title, url, feedRSS];
NSLog(@"MainViewController::createPostInFeed> Before fetchRequest for %@ (%@)", title, url);
NSError *error = nil;
fetchedItems = [moc countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"MainViewController::createPostInFeed> After fetchRequest for %@ (%@)", title, url); // THIS NSLOGGING NEVER HAPPENS
```

**Update (4):**
New profiler pic with call tree inverted.
[image]

Comment: Could you show the code that instantiates your MOCs? I ask because how you instantiate your MOCs might be what is causing the problem...

Comment: Questions: 1. Are you able to log the error from your `executeFetchRequest:` method?  2. Where do you set your `NSPredicate` variables `title`, `url` and `feed.rss`? 3. Out of my curiosity and ignorance, why do you lock your `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` when running this `NSFetchRequest`?

Comment: Hello: **(1)** no, the app just freezes, nothing happen anymore even in the profiler. this is the last known position in the code. **(2)** watch above, the call to ``createPostInFeed``: I need this request to  ensure I won't create a duplicate feed. **(3)** I also tried without, I think I read somewhere that this operation was sensible and I should ensure I am alone when reading the psc data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your goal with `createPostInFeed`?  You show that you are doing a fetch but what do you do with that fetch?  Is this a "insert or update" check? or is it just a "insert or skip" test?

Any fetch is going to lock the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and cause your application to *potentially* lock up while the fetch is being performed.  There are ways to mitigate that:

1. Run Instruments
2. Make your fetches more efficient
3. If you don't need objects (in a insert or skip test) then do a count instead
4. Fetch on a background queue and make sure your main MOC has all the objects it needs to avoid a lock

What does your instruments profile show you?

What does `createPostInFeed` do with the results of that fetch?

Comment: Hello Marcus, Thanks for your reply. I do that fetch to know if I am not about to create a duplicate Post in a Feed (with an already existing url+title+feed): I want to avoid duplicates, that's it. I replaced the ``[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]`` line with ``[moc countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]`` but it still freezes at the same point. So ``fetchedItems``is now an int but the problem remains. I can see it as a put NSLogs just before and after: it never gets past. The whole ``createPostInFeed`` takes place within a ``_temporaryMOC performBlock``.

Comment: You are doing three string comparisons and a table join in that predicate.  That will get expensive over time which is what I am guessing you are seeing.  But first, what does time profiler in Instruments tell you is going on during that freeze?  That **must** be your first step.  Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Hello Marcus, I just uploaded a picture of the Time profiler in action.

Comment: Invert the call tree so we can see where the expense is.  I would also focus the time profiler on the part where there is activity so we can see the expense.  Or upload the trace file somewhere...

Comment: Hello Marcus, new pic uploaded. You can find the trace file [here](http://linuxette.net/trucz/Instruments.zip). *Thanks!*

Comment: OK, that was useful.  What does `-[RSSParser parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:]` look like?  Seems you are spending the bulk of your time creating `NSDateFormatter` instances.

Comment: Marcus, I will mark this question as answered as I indeed have to polish my RSSParser which indeed perform loads of background ops, maybe one of these is interferring with some background op somewhere else. **Thanks a lot for your kind help!**

Comment: If you run into another one, open another SO and ping me on twitter.

Comment: I use neither Twitter nor Facebook but I am sure we can find a way, maybe using the email address you published on cimg.com?